# Modal no sombrea toda las partes de la mi pagina

Tags: php

hola estoy tratando introducir modal a mi pagina pero tengo este problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el modal esta en una div y el encabezado y el menu también

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo leer [ask] y de paso haz el [tour] pues tu pregunta es muy ambigua por lo que puede que no obtenga respuestas o termine cerrada, comparte el codigo de tu modal o bien crea un [example]

Comment: Adicionalmente... esta pregunta parece no tener nada que ver con PHP, tiene que ver con CSS. Saludos.